# Run python program on startup in background on Intel Galileo

Tags: linux, boot, python

I have a python program that is an infinity loop and send some data to my database.

I want this python script to run when I power my Intel Galileo. I tried to make a sh script `python myprogram.py` and made it run on startup in `etc/init.d`. When I restarted my Galileo, nothing happened-Linux didn't load, Arduino sketch didn't load and even my computer didn't recognize it.

I guess this happened because the python program was an infinity loop. Is there a way that I can run my system without problems and run my python script on startup?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your script

Answer (score 0):

The scripts in /etc/init.d are run at startup/boot.

Your python takes the control at boot and run in infinite loops causing problem while booting

Replace your script with below given:

```
python myprogram.py &
```

It will run the py program in background.